# Using grep and regex to extract words from a file that contain only one kind of vowel

Tags: regex, grep

I have a large dictionary file that contains one word per line.

I want to extract all lines that contain only one kind of vowel, so "see" and "best" and "levee" and "whenever" would be extracted, but "like" or "house" or "and" wouldn't. It's fine for me having to go over the file a few times, changing the vowel I'm looking for each time.

This command: `grep -io '\b[eqwrtzpsdfghjklyxcvbnm]*\b' dictionary.txt`

returns no words containing any other vowels but E, but it also gives me words like BBC or BMW. How can I make the contained vowel a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Awk attempt which collects all the hits in a single pass over the input file, then prints each bucket.

```
awk 'BEGIN { split("a:e:i:o:u", vowel, ":")
    c = "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]"
    for (v in vowel)
      regex = (regex ? regex "|" : "") "^" c "*" vowel[v] c "*(" vowel[v] c "]*)*$" }
    $0 ~ regex { for (v in vowel) if ($0 ~ vowel[v]) {
        hit[v] = ( hit[v] ? hit[v] ORS : "") $0
        next } }
    END { for (v in vowel) {
        printf "=== %s ===\n", vowel[v]
        print hit[v] } }' /usr/share/dict/words
```

You'll notice that it prints words with syllabic *y* like *jolly* and *cycle.* A more complex regex should fix that, though the really thorny cases (like *rhyme*) need a more sophisticated model of English orthography.

The regex is clumsy because Awk does not support backreferences; an earlier version of this answer contained a simpler regex which would work with `grep -E` or similar, but then collect all matches in the same bucket.

Demo: https://ideone.com/wNrvPu

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
grep -i '^[^aiou]*e[^aiou]*$'
```

?

Comment: This doesn't work, as it excludes any string that begins with an e. It does match "levee", but doesn't match "elf". Not sure why, though.

Comment: @kinkybudget Sorry, that was just a typo in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using -P (perl) option:

```
^(?=.*e)[^aiou]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    (?=.*e)     # positive lookahead, make sure we at least 1 "e"
    [^aiou]+    # 1 or more any character that is not vowel 
$               # end of line
```

---

```
cat file.txt
see
best
levee
whenever
like
house
and
BBC 
BMW

grep -P '^(?=.*e)[^aiou]+$' file.txt
see
best
levee
whenever
```